# Invariance of the Lagrangian of non-Abelian gauge field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

I try to prove that the Lagrangian density :

$$ \mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{4}~ G_{i\mu\nu}~ G^{i\mu\nu}, $$

invariant under $SU(2)$ and $U(1)$ symmetries,

where:

$$ G_{i}^{\mu\nu} = F_{i}^{\mu\nu} + g \epsilon_{ijk} W^\mu_j W^\nu_k   $$

and:

$$ F_{i}^{\mu\nu} = \partial^\nu W^\mu_i - \partial^\mu W^\nu_i $$

I found in Ryder's book " quantum field theory" equation (3.170) that $ G_{i}^{\mu\nu}$ transforms under SU(2) symmetry as:

$$ G_{i}^{\mu\nu '} = S~  G_{i}^{\mu\nu}~ S^{-1}, $$

So that:

$$ \mathcal{L'} = - \frac{1}{4}~ G_{i\mu\nu ' }~ G^{i\mu\nu ' } = - \frac{1}{4}~ S~  G_{i\mu\nu}~ S^{-1}~  S~  G_{i}^{\mu\nu}~ S^{-1} = 
- \frac{1}{4}~ S~  G_{i\mu\nu}~ G_{i}^{\mu\nu}~ S^{-1} $$

Now i think I can not move $ S^{-1} $ across $  G_{i}^{\mu\nu}~ G_{i\mu\nu} $,

Also this is the transformation under $SU(1)$, what about $U(1)$ invariance?

Answer (score 3):

1. The equation 
   $$ G_i^{\mu\nu} \mapsto S G_i^{\mu\nu} S^{-1}$$
   does not make any sense. $G_i^{\mu\nu}$ is a number, a matrix like $S$ cannot act on it, so it would just be scalar multiplication, and you could move the $S$ past the $G_i^{\mu\nu}$ to make the transformation a do-nothing transformation. The correct transformation behaviour of the field strength under a gauge transformation $g : \mathbb{R}^4\to\mathrm{SU}(2)$ can be derived from the fundamental transformation behaviour of the gauge field:
   $$ W^\mu \mapsto g W^\mu g^{-1} + g^{-1}\partial^\mu g$$
   where now $W^\mu$ is $\mathfrak{su}(2)$-valued (i.e. it's in the Lie algebra of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$). You should find that
   $$ G^{\mu\nu}\mapsto gG^{\mu\nu}g^{-1}$$
   where, again, $G^{\mu\nu}$ is an $\mathfrak{su}(2)$-valued object.
2. The Lagrangian is a trace on group indices, $G_{i\mu\nu}G^{i\mu\nu} = \mathrm{tr}(G_{\mu\nu}G^{\mu\nu})$. Simply use cyclic invariance of the trace to show that the Lagrangian is invariant.

Comment: You mean : $ \mathcal{L'} = - \frac{1}{4}~ G_{i\mu\nu ' }~ G^{i\mu\nu ' } =   - \frac{1}{4}~ tr (  G_{\mu\nu}~   G^{\mu\nu} )   = 
- \frac{1}{4}~ tr ( S~  G_{\mu\nu}~ G^{\mu\nu}~ S^{-1}) = - \frac{1}{4}~ tr ( S~ S^{-1} G_{\mu\nu}~ G^{\mu\nu})  = - \frac{1}{4}~ tr (  G_{\mu\nu}~ G^{\mu\nu})  = \mathcal{L}$ . So can U(1) invarince proven here as well ?